# How to update Mac iTerm2 terminal prompt

Tags: command-line, bash, mac, terminal, iterm2

I am using Mac 10.13.2 High Sierra. I made the following `.bash_profile` file to see the file path along with the prompt and if it has any Git repository it shows the Git status as well.

All is working except the long prompt name.

My bash file contains:-

```
if [ -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion ]; then
  . $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion
fi

source ~/git-prompt.sh


precmd() {
  __posh_git_ps1 '\u@\h:\w ' '$ '
}

if [ $ITERM_SESSION_ID ]; then
  export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033];${PWD##*/}\007"; ':"$PROMPT_COMMAND";
fi

PROMPT_COMMAND='__posh_git_ps1 "\u@\h:\w " "\\\$ ";'$PROMPT_COMMAND

export PS1="$: "
```

The Bash prompt looks like this in the picture:-

[image: Bash prompt]

I don't want the long `masum@Admin-MacBook-Pro:~/` text in this prompt. Just a simple `$:` is enough for me.

I read that the following line should make my prompt like this.

```
export PS1="$: "
```

But it has no effect. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `PROMPT_COMMAND` is set,
the value of `PS1` is dynamically overwritten by it,
and whatever you set to it manually will not matter.

To make your prompt shorter, adjust `PROMPT_COMMAND`, for example:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='__posh_git_ps1 "" "\\$ ";'
```

In your `PROMPT_COMMAND` the `\u` is replaced by your user name, the `\h` is replaced by your hostname and the `\w` by your working directory so you can adjust your prompt as you desire. Check out the [bash prompt HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/) for more details.